# GPU - how many scalar channels

Tags: cuda, shader, gpu, nvidia

Im a bit confuzed how many scalar chanels ( i mean "gpu simd width" x "gpu simd cores")
GPU have, for example my own GPU "nvidia geforce gt 610")

it has 48 shader processors (i hoppe each od such processor has separate SIMD
as a processing word), some say also that mosc common (?) gpu simd width is 32 
floats/ints - so are my calculations right and it has just 48x32 = 1536 scalar 
channels? (i mean when all shader processors are at work 1536 floats can be processed in one step)

Comment: What do you mean by SIMD width? Do you mean "warp size"? If so, it is measured in threads, not `float`/`ints`. Also, each streaming multiprocessor of the GT610 has `48` CUDA cores and on each core you run only one thread, not a warp. Your post is based on erroneous premises and also uses an umbiguous termonilogy.

Comment: what do you mean wrap size? Im newbi ehere and do not understand this terminology so it is clear that i can be confuzed.. Im interested how many scalar channels it can run in parallel, for some who knows the theme i think this question could be understandable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [GT610](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_600_series) is a [cc 2.1 GPU](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#compute-capabilities) with a single [SM](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#hardware-implementation).   That SM contains 48 CUDA cores (=shader processors).  Each CUDA core is capable of producing one single precision scalar result per clock cycle.  Each CUDA core does not have a separate SIMD path to process a SIMD word.  It processes one scalar element per clock cycle.

It has 48 scalar channels.  48 floats can be processed in one step, i.e. in one clock cycle.

The SIMT vector width of GT610 is 32, just as it is on all CUDA GPUs  -- this is the "warp size".  This means when a CUDA instruction is issued, it will be executed across 32 threads per instruction issue.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that just because the GT610 can only process 48 floats per clock cycle doesn't mean that you only need 48-way parallelism. Each operation takes more than one clock cycle to "return", and other threads can operate in the space between the operation and it "returning" with no overhead.

Comment: could you maybe yet add what is cc 2.1 and what is SM?

Comment: @jez so what is effective paralelism is this only 48 sclar channels?

Comment: At least for CUDA codes, *all* GPUs require significantly more available threads than available compute resources (i.e. cores) in order to hide latency and get the highest level of performance out of the GPU.

Comment: added doc links in answer for cc (compute capability) and SM (streaming multiprocessor)

Comment: alright, does you maybe know what numbers are most crusial to estimate number of processing chips onthe board, 48 shader cores would be the first, is there some secondary number to notice?